# Laravel 4 global installation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to test drive laravel 4 yet of course I have to install Composer first. Now there are two installation types (local vs. global). I want a global installation to avoid using

`php composer.phar` and rather use `composer`. That said the instructions shown in their website shows:

```
$ mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

I am using shared hosting on justhost and this is not going to work because inside bin there is no composer. Where should I move it to to ensure it is global?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put it anywhere in path. So you can check yours by running

```
echo $PATH
```

and you should see something like:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Then you choose one of those (delimited by ":") and move it to there:

```
mv composer.phar /usr/sbin/composer
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually shared hosts won't give you the permissions to access bin-directories , so the only option is to make a  "local" composer installation on your shared host (assuming you have terminal access on your host account) . Most likely , the example that you talk about , presupposes  a full terminal access into the aforementioned  directories . Game isn't over though , many alternative options could be adopted .
 For instance :
1) Getting a VPS account (that's the most expensive solution)
2) Setting up a local development environment (MAMP , WAMP , XAMP , Vagrant) and transferring the final project to your shared host (with FTP/SFTP )
3) Using a PAAS (platform as a service) . Amazon has a one year free subscription option , registering must be done with a Credit Card though. A couple PAAS services (with free options) that really deserves attention are [fortabbit](http://fortrabbit.com/)  and [phpcloud](http://www.phpcloud.com/)